# как изменить кодировку pandas.read_sql

Tags: python, sql, pandas

Такая проблема, считываю базу данных через pd.read_sql, открывается DF и не могу привести символы в читаемый вид:

```
pd.read_sql("select top 1000  * FROM dbo.ActTime ORDER BY datetime DESC ", conn)
```

```
0      ÏÅ×Ü  Ò-19                                    ...
1      ÏÐÅÑÑ   ÏÀÎ637Ô2                              ...
2      ÌÀØÈÍÀ ÒÅÐÌÈ×ÅÑÊÎÉ ÐÅÇÊÈ Suprarex SXE-P3 4500 ...
3      ÑÂÀÐÎ×ÍÛÉ ÖÅÍÒÐ CaB 300(¹6)                   ...
4      ÑÂÀÐÎ×ÍÛÉ ÖÅÍÒÐ CaB 300(¹7)                   ...
                             ...                        
228    ÂÀÍÍÀ ÇÀÊÀËÎ×ÍÀß WAB-25.20.40/15/90           ...
229    ÂÀÍÍÀ ÇÀÊÀËÎ×ÍÀß WAB-25.20.40/15/90           ...
230    ÏÅ×Ü  Ò-19                                    ...
231    ÏÅ×Ü  Ò-19                                    ...
232    ÏÅ×Ü  Ò-19                                    ...
Name: Name, Length: 233, dtype: object
```

Что можно сделать?

Comment: вам нужно установить кодировку в коннекторе, а не в методе read_sql

Comment: Попробовал, но тот же самый эффект

Comment: Что именно попробовали? Какую кодировку указали? Похоже по умолчанию используется кодировка cp1252, а нужно (в данном случае, судя по тексту) использовать cp1251.

Comment: engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pymssql://scada:12345678@asutp-1c-201/Moto", echo=False, encoding='cp1251'), все равно тоже самое

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй передать входную кодировку, судя по [декодеру](https://www.online-decoder.com/ru) это **`iso-8859-1`**:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pymssql://scada:12345678@asutp-1c-201/Moto", echo=False, encoding='iso-8859-1')
```

Comment: Судя по результату, там и так какая-то латинская  кодировка используется. Чтобы русский текст отображался наоборот нужно кириллическую кодировку указывать.

Comment: Отлично, спасибо, получилось